# How to create uniform superpostion of N states where N is not power of 2

Tags: superposition

Many textbooks only consider superposition of N states where N is a power of 2. For example, H|0> is a uniform superpostion of |0> and |1> and N=2.
How to construct quantum circuit for a uniform superpostion of arbitrary number of states, like N=3?